# Поиск слов в бинарном дереве поиска по первым буквам

Tags: python, python-3.x, бинарное-дерево

У меня есть функция поиска слова по первым символам в бинарном дереве поиска, но она находит только первое слово и останавливается. Как мне сделать вывод всех слов, которые начинаются на key ?

```
def search(tree, key):
        while True:
            try:
                if tree.value.startswith(key):
                    print(tree.value, tree.count)
                    return
                elif key < tree.value:
                    tree = tree.left
                elif key > tree.value:
                    tree = tree.right
            except AttributeError:
                print('Word' + key + ' is not found')
                return
```

Comment: Посмотрите [префиксное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, вариант с минимальными изменениями, наверное, такой:

```
if tree.value.startswith(key):
    print(tree.value, tree.count)
    search(tree.left, key)  # <--
    search(tree.right, key) # <--
    return
```

По-хорошему нужно ещё уровень рекурсии отслеживать, передавая ещё один параметр в функцию и при `exception` ничего не выводить, если мы не на самом верхнем уровне вызова функции.

Но вообще хотелось бы данные с примером дерева. Всё может быть и не настолько просто.

Comment: Ваш пример проводит полный обход дерева. Я думаю TC хочет что-то более быстрое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Обход, но только подходящего поддерева и только на ту глубину, пока префикс совпадает.

Comment: Глупость сказал, прошу прощения.